# Inserting SVG element in editable div

Tags: html, svg, execcommand

I have an editable div in my HTML and I am inserting an SVG element in the same.
The element is as follows:

```
<svg width="1.5em" height="1.5em"><use xlink:href="hrefLink"></use></svg>
```

I am inserting this element using `document.execCommand('insertHTML')` method. However, I am facing the below-stated problems -

1. The cursor is not getting set after the SVG element. The cursor position always remains before the SVG element. And any text or anything else gets inserted before the SVG element.
2. I found one method to element the above-stated problem i.e. by keeping a `&nbsp;` after the SVG tag which seems to work. However, when there are 2 consecutive SVGs, say 'AB' and I put the cursor between them and try to delete 'A' using backspace, it's deleting both the SVGs.

Comment: I think you're always going to have that problem with the cursor if you put the <use> tag inside the SVG. One idea: is it possible to call the "hrefLink" using the fill attribute? Also, there's a solution recommended here: https://jsfiddle.net/nrx9yvw9/5/

Comment: I don't think the jsfiddle solution is gonna work as I won't know the exact count of characters after which the cursor needs to be placed.

Comment: so, exactly where do you want the cursor to end up? The question is a bit unclear.  By my reckoning, you can use the JSFiddle solution and modify to find specific characters and then pop the cursor in.